# Play Framework and Forms

Tags: forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am currently using the Play Framework but there seems to be rather little information regarding Forms.

At the moment I got something that looks like this:
The route is:

```
GET /test  controllers.Application.testMethod()
```

The method:

```
public static Result testMethod(){
   //handles the Form
}
```

The NameResidencePair class:

```
public static class NameResidencePair{
   public String name;
   public String residence; 
}
```

The scala.html page featuring a form

```
@(aForm: Form[NameResidencePair])

@import helper._
@form(action = routes.Application.testMethod) {

@inputText(
field = userForm("name")
)

@inputText(
field = userForm("residence")
)
}
```

What if I still want a form but one of the values, like residence, is always the same value. Example: residence = "On a cloud". I still want to pass it via the form but I don't want a textfield. So in other words, I want to pass a form with name and residence but only the name should be editable and visible in an inputfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is a hidden form field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="residence" value="On a cloud">
```

[There is no form template helper](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.package) for creating a hidden field, but pasting that line into your code should not be too much work. :-)

But please not, just because it's hidden, you cannot assume that the value will always be "On a cloud". This just means "the form field is a hidden one", the user can still send an arbitrary value. So please still check the user input.